# Redirect User to the different page depends upon the userType in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I am new to the `react and redux`. Here, I am trying to redirect user to the different pages on the basis of the userType. What I have is  ,

My main.js file

```
class Main extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.isUserAuthenticated();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <div>
          {this.props.isFetching && <Loading />}
          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/create-job" component={NewJob} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/create-job/new" component={SelectCriteriaNewJob} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/view-job" component={ViewJob} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/resume-list/:jdId" component={ResumeList} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/DashBoard" component={DashBoard} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/*" component={NotFound} something="foo" />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Now , Login action is there. where I am redirecting user on one page where it decides where to redirect user on the basis of the data that I got.Currently not the username logic .

In the login action ,

```
  export function fetchToken(bodyjson) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_REQUEST
    });
    let url = LOGIN_PATH + "username=" + bodyjson.userName + "&password=" + bodyjson.password;
    return post(url, bodyjson)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          localStorage.setItem('user', bodyjson.username);
          localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.payload.access_token);
          history.push('/');
          dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            data: response.payload,
          })
        }
        else {
          dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAILED,
            data: response.status,
          });
        }
      })
  }
}
```

Now in this action I am redirecting user to the  `/` page, where ,the component looks like,

```
  render() {
        if (this.state.isloading) {
          return null;
        }
        else if (this.props.jobs) {
          return <JobList />;
        } else if (this.props.error) {
          return <ErrorComponent />
        }
        else {
          return <Redirect to="/create-job" />
        }
      }
    }
```

Now,when user logs in that time I got one token which is a `JWT` token, that token has some information. So, Here I want to redirect user to the `/Dashboard` page if the usertype is of admin. So, there may be diff roles so,
Is there any way through which I can do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried so far. Also can you give more information by giving a code sandbox of the same.